# How to change from NTFS to "noramal FS" in USB memory?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

Several years ago, I change my usb file system(FS) from default *FS* to *NTFS*. but now, I want to change to default *FS*.

What is the way to change that *FS*?

Machine Enviroment: *macOSX 10.14*

```
default Format: MS-DOS(FAT32)
current Format: Windows NT FileSystem(NTFS)
```

USB internal file by terminal

```
  >>ls -l -FG -a
total 6403240
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 takezakiyuuta  staff       2352  8  2  2018 $UGM*
drwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff       8192  8 23  2018 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 10 root           wheel        320  2 21 19:39 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff         12  8  9  2018 .avm_speed_test2*
drwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff          0  8 10  2018 .fseventsd/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff         11  8 23  2018 .hd_keepalive*
drwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff      16384  8 23  2018 .index/
drwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff      16384  8 23  2018 .thumb/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  354368793  8 18  2018 180818-1039.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  156281700  8 18  2018 180818-1042.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  232452505  8 18  2018 180818-1044.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  164182010  8 20  2018 180820-1817.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  470749844  8 20  2018 180820-1820.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  299472449  8 20  2018 180820-1824.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  112263523  8 23  2018 180823-2044.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff   56539836  8 23  2018 180823-2046.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff   42780723  8 23  2018 180823-2048.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  290799372  8 23  2018 180823-2050.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  365304821  8 23  2018 180823-2052.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  396741824  8 23  2018 180823-2055.mp4*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 takezakiyuuta  staff  336483041  8 23  2018 180823-2058.mp4*
drwxr-xr-x@  1 takezakiyuuta  staff          0  8  2  2018 System Volume Information/
```

Comment: Porpose I want to change above is adding files and removing files.
Currently I cannot do.

Comment: I would suggest that the easiest way to do that is to insert the USB drive on a machine that understands both NTFS and FAT32, a Windows machine for example, copy all of the files from the USB drive to a temp folder on the host machine, format the USB drive to FAT32 (erasing everything on this USB drive, so be sure files were actually copied), then copy the files back to the USB drive.  As long as the host machine has the room to store the files, temporarily, this is an easy solution.